# How to convert a text file having multipe duplicate keys and printing it with their associated values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
RequestId=159dd0dc-3ac2-11e7-9f57-b7548c7a91e2

global-action-trace=15a01af3-3ac2-11e7-babe-0a5b00b90000

EOE

RequestId=12780045-3ac2-11e7-8dc6-f7c2b766d8e7

global-action-trace=1278c342-3ac2-11e7-babe-0a5b00b90000

EOE
```

I want to print only the `key(RequestId)` and value how it is possible in Python

Comment: Have you tried with a `regex`? It would be a pretty simple one.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: or read the file in line by line and if `RequestId` is in the line, add the `line[10:]` to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex:

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """RequestId=159dd0dc-3ac2-11e7-9f57-b7548c7a91e2

global-action-trace=15a01af3-3ac2-11e7-babe-0a5b00b90000

EOE

RequestId=12780045-3ac2-11e7-8dc6-f7c2b766d8e7

global-action-trace=1278c342-3ac2-11e7-babe-0a5b00b90000

EOE"""
print(re.findall("RequestId=(.*)", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['159dd0dc-3ac2-11e7-9f57-b7548c7a91e2', '12780045-3ac2-11e7-8dc6-f7c2b766d8e7']
```

Comment: I am also having  a Time=49.217518 ms  which is different for 
different requested Id in the same file how can I print it
                                                 RequestId=12780045-3ac2-11e7-8dc6-f7c2b766d8e7 Time=371.659573

RequestId=246ae44d-3ac6-11e7-b37d-67399e5d4706 Time=55.300253
in this form

Answer (score 0):

Just use `regex`. The expression inside the parenthesis `()` is the thing you want to extract.

```
print re.findall('RequestId=([A-Za-z0-9 -=]+)', s)
#Output:
#['159dd0dc-3ac2-11e7-9f57-b7548c7a91e2 global-action-trace=15a01af3-3ac2-11e7-babe-0a5b00b90000 EOE RequestId=12780045-3ac2-11e7-8dc6-f7c2b766d8e7 global-action-trace=1278c342-3ac2-11e7-babe-0a5b00b90000 EOE']
```

Comment: How can we add multiple search example I want to search for Request Id as well as Time